# calculating galois groups of $K= \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[8]{2},i]$ over various fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

this was an old homework problem that I didnt quite understand, could someone provide some insight to any of the parts?

We are supposed to prove that given $K= \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[8]{2},i]$

a) $G(K/\mathbb{Q}[i])\cong \mathbb{Z}_8$

b) $G(K/\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}])\cong D_4$

c) $G(K/\mathbb{Q}[i\sqrt{2}])\cong $ Quaternion Group

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$K$ is the splitting field over ${\mathbb Q}$ of $x^8-2$, which has roots $tw^i$ ($0 \le i \le 7$), where $t = \sqrt[8]{2}$ and $w = (1+i)/\sqrt{2}$ is a primitive $8$th root of $1$.

So we need to work out the Galois group of $K$ over ${\mathbb Q}$. This acts transitively on the roots, so there is an automorphism $\alpha$ withs $\alpha(t)= tw$. So $\alpha(\sqrt{2}) = \alpha(t^4) = t^4w^4 = -t^4 = -\sqrt{2}$. Another automorphism, $\beta$, is complex conjugation. By replacing $\alpha$ by $\alpha\beta$ if necessary, we can assume that $\alpha(i)=i$, and hence $\alpha(w) = -w = w^5$.

We can now calculate the action of $\alpha$ on all roots, and we find $\alpha$ is the $8$-cycle $(0,1,6,7,4,5,2,3)$, where I have just written $i$ for the root $tw^i$. We can also calculate $\beta = (1,7)(2,6)(3,5)$, and we find that $\beta\alpha\beta = \alpha^3$, so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ generate a group of order $16$, which is equal to the degree $|K:{\mathbb Q}|$, and hence is the full Galois group of the extension. (This group is sometimes known as the *semidihedral group*.)

The Galois groups you have been asked to calculate are the subgroups with the specified fixed fields. We chose $\alpha$ with $\alpha(i)=i$, so ${\mathbb Q}[i]$ is the fixed field of the subgroup $\langle \alpha \rangle$, which is cyclic of order $8$.

Similarly, you will find that the subgroups $\langle \alpha^2,\beta \rangle$ and $\langle \alpha^2,\alpha\beta \rangle$ fix $\sqrt{2}$ and $i\sqrt{2}$, respectively.